# Getting rid of the centering in first line of gather?

Tags: align, amsmath, amsart, gather

Suppose we have the following code:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsaddr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in,top=3cm}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\mathbb{P}\left(\mathcal{D}\left((0,1),\{x_{w-1}\}_{w\in \text{\textbf{V}}},\mathcal{S}(\mathscr{U}(13/6,F_2^{\star},1),1)\right)\right)=\\
\left\{{y}\bigg/\left({\sum\limits_{z\in \mathcal{D}\left((0,1),\{x_{w-1}\}_{w\in \text{\textbf{V}}},\mathcal{S}(\mathscr{U}(13/6,F_2^{\star},1),1)\right)} z}\right):y\in \mathcal{D}\left((0,1),\{x_{w-1}\}_{w\in \text{\textbf{V}}},\mathcal{S}(\mathscr{U}(13/6,F_2^{\star},1),1)\right)\right\}\approx\nonumber\\
 \left\{{y}\bigg/(8.08697):y\in\left\{1.1,1.50333,2.0025,1.58114,0.9\right\}\right\}\approx\nonumber\\
 \left\{\frac{1.1}{8.08697},\frac{1.50333}{8.08697},\frac{2.0025}{8.086097},\frac{1.58114}{8.08697},\frac{0.9}{8.08697}\right\}\approx\nonumber\\
 \left\{.136021,.185895,.123656,.24762,.195517,.11129\right\}\nonumber
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Question:** How do we get rid of the centering in the first line of `gather`?

Comment: use multline instead

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot of the output of your code. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend that you find an abbreviation, say, `\mathcal{D}^{\star}`, for the repetitive

```
\mathcal{D}\left((0,1),\{x_{w-1}\}_{w\in \text{\textbf{V}}},
\mathcal{S}(\mathscr{U}(13/6,F_2^{\star},1),1)\right)
```

string. This would allow the multirow material to be typeset much more compactly than before, as follows. (Note also that I've switched to an `equation`/`aligned` combination. This guarantees that but one equation number will be generated, without having to resort to a multitude of `\nonumber` directives.)

[image]

And, by all means, do please replace all instances of `\text{\textbf{V}}` with `\mathbf{V}`.

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsaddr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in,top=3cm}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
% amssymb % loaded automatically by 'amsart' doc. class
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % for '\mathscr' macro

\begin{document}
Put $\mathcal{D}^{\star} = \mathcal{D}\bigl( (0,1),
\{x_{w-1}\}_{w\in\mathbf{V}},
\mathcal{S}(\mathscr{U}(13/6,F_2^{\star},1),1)\bigr)$. Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{D}^{\star}) 
&=\biggl\{ 
  y \Big/ \smash{\smashoperator{\sum_{z\in\mathcal{D}^{\star}}}}
  z : y \in \mathcal{D}^{\star}
  \biggr\} \\
&\approx
 \biggl\{ y \Big/(8.08697):y\in\{1.1,1.50333,2.0025,1.58114,0.9\}\biggr\} 
 \\
&\approx \biggl\{
   \frac{1.1}{8.08697},
   \frac{1.50333}{8.08697},
   \frac{2.0025}{8.086097},
   \frac{1.58114}{8.08697},
   \frac{0.9}{8.08697}
   \biggr\}\\
&\approx\bigl\{0.136021, 0.185895, 0.123656, 0.24762, 0.195517, 0.11129 \bigr\} \,.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```